Why does the Flutter WebView package require you to use ".postMessage()"?
I have the Flutter WebView package in my pubspec.yaml. The webview has a JavaScript channels feature. You can a define a Dart function with a name like Foo for example. But for that function to handle parameters, it needs an onMessageReceived() method. Then, to call the Dart code from the JS context, you need to do Foo.postMessage() instead of just Foo().
Why is it implemented this way? Why isn't just straighforward?
stackoverflow is telling me this question appears subjective, so I'll clarify again: Why does calling a Dart function require tacking on  .postMessage()? Why was it designed this way?

When you use the WebView with a JavaScript channel it establishes a two way communication between your Dart code and the JavaScript code that runs in the page loaded into the WebView. You can't directly call a Dart function from the JavaScript code, this is what the channel is designed to handle in a way. The only thing you can pass from JavaScript to Dart is a string using the JavaScriptMessage class.
You set up the channel using the WebViewController like this:
myWebViewController.addJavaScriptChannel('myChannel',
    onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) async {
  // your code here which handles the content from postMessage
});

After you load a page the expression myChannel will be defined and accessible in the JavaScript code and can be called like this,
myChannel.postMessage('your string message here');

And from Dart:
myWebViewController.runJavaScript('your JavaScript expression here');

or
final result = await myWebViewController.runJavaScriptReturningResult('your JavaScript expression here');

In your question if Foo is a Dart function, you can't use Foo.postMessage() from the JavaScript code, only if Foo is the name of the channel you created
with addJavaScriptChannel.
The communication is basically passing strings between Dart and JavaScript, the JavaScript side evaluates the string and tries to run it as a JavaScript expression. It fails if it is not valid in the context of the page's JavaScript code.
From the Dart side you have to pass everything as string and if there is a result from JavaScript that will also be a string. There is no way to directly call a Dart function from WebView, you are restricted to passing strings.

Thanks for your answer Peter, but I feel youv'e only helped clarify the problem. I guess I was hoping that someone from the flutter dev team might see this question. Because my question is a bit deeper than what you have explained. I'm asking if there is some advantage to having to use .postMessage. Android Kotlin has webviews and what it calls javascript interfaces. You can define functions and call them like Foo(). So why doesn't Flutter just do that?

I see, sorry for that. I also use @JavascriptInterface to define Java functions in a native Android app and call them directly from the Flutter WebView after setting up in Java with addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "CallJava"); and calling CallJava.myFunction... from JavaScript.

I hope you get answer from someone else, my guess is that because Flutter has many platforms they wanted to have a solution which is platform independent and passing strings seemed to be a good way. But it's only a guess.
